# Merge Mutilple pdf blobs into one

Tags: javascript, blob

Okay so I'm converting html into pdfs, the pdf returned from my backend I convert to a new Blob with type: 'application/pdf', this all works fine. I now want to merge multiple Blobs into one. I'm using the following function to do so.

```
function ConcatenateBlobs(blobs, type, callback) {
                var buffers = [];

                var index = 0;

                function readAsArrayBuffer() {
                    if (!blobs[index]) {
                        return concatenateBuffers();
                    }
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        buffers.push(event.target.result);
                        index++;
                        readAsArrayBuffer();
                    };
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blobs[index]);
                }

                readAsArrayBuffer();

                function concatenateBuffers() {
                    var byteLength = 0;
                    buffers.forEach(function(buffer) {
                        byteLength += buffer.byteLength;
                    });

                    var tmp = new Uint16Array(byteLength);
                    var lastOffset = 0;
                    buffers.forEach(function(buffer) {
                        // BYTES_PER_ELEMENT == 2 for Uint16Array
                        var reusableByteLength = buffer.byteLength;
                        if (reusableByteLength % 2 != 0) {
                            buffer = buffer.slice(0, reusableByteLength - 1)
                        }
                        tmp.set(new Uint16Array(buffer), lastOffset);
                        lastOffset += reusableByteLength;
                    });

                    var blob = new Blob([tmp.buffer], {
                        type: type
                    });

                    callback(blob);
                }
            }
```

But for some reason I am only getting the last pdf in the array to show as the result.

Comment: You need to combine the pages from the PDFs. Not simply concatenate them. For this you need a PDF library that can combine pages from multiple PDFs into one.

Comment: Can it even be done that easily? PDF documents have set header and footer identifiers etc.